# Jenkins and notifications

Tags: jenkins

I'm just starting to learn Jenkins watching some online videos. One thing that puzzles me is how does one avoid getting notifications when committing changes that you know will cause the compile to fail.

For example, I make a change in a class and commit it. Other developers haven't yet got the updated file, so they need to first retrieve the update, change their code and then commit their changes before Jenkins carries out a compile.

I'm using Git for code versioning. Am I suppose to use Git separately from Jenkins and make sure the app compiles locally before committing the changes to Jenkins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Jenkins as you want. Specially, you don't have to configure Jenkins to run a job on each commit. You can configure it to run some jobs every x hours, etc.

If you prefer run a job automatically on commits, but you don't want to break your job if you know a commit will not compile properly, maybe use Git branches to organize your work. For example, you develeop in a dev branch (or other branches, one for each developer in your team) and when a feature is complete, merge it to the master branch. If Jenkins is configured to run a job on this branch, it will be ok.

Keep in mind that Jenkins is very flexible. When you will understand how it can work, you will probably have ideas for the best configuration for YOUR workflow ;)

Comment: Your idea sounds good. Even if I do use a master branch that gets compiled when it gets updated, is it still quite likely that the compile will fail regularly? I guess what I am concerned about is how do ALL developers know to get the latest copy of all modules and make sure that on some specific date/time when a compile is to be done, that the compile will most likely succeed? Does this have anything to do with Jenkins or is this just some form of communication rule that needs to be implemented among developers?

Comment: IMO it's only rules in your team. Once again Jenkins will work as you will configure it. You don't have to adapt your workflow to Jenkins in most case, but you will find a way to adapt jenkins to your rules.

Answer (score 2):

The normal way we since this is too use the Branching of git. The master branch should always compile. Only that is auto build. If you have a breaking change, you develop it in a feature branch, and later commit that to the master branch